# What should be the data structure before tokenizing the text based data for Tranformer-Based Model?

Tags: nlp, transformer-model, gpt-3

I have seen some examples where people are mostly getting text-based datasets in the form of JSON, but I don't understand the reason why. Can anyone explain why I need to convert my data into a dictionary before tokenizing it for a Tranfomer-based model i.e (BERT, GPT-3, T5... etc). What I have so far learned, we need to know the dataset, and the attention mask will tell us which token needs to be targeted. But what about before tokenizing, even on HuggingFace no one talks about that, all examples gives one sentence example. I think it will be a great help if there is any explanation.